# recursive function return problem in java

Tags: java, recursion

I created this recursive function but I think the return statement causes a problem. Somehow my output in the console is incorrect. There are some redundant values and the output is just not correct. There is an example you can check out further down.

**Example:**

```
16 - 5 = 11  
11 - 5 = 6  
1 - 5 = -4 --- the number reached negative.    
 5 by 5 until we're back where we started.  
-4 + 5 = 1  
1 + 5 = 6  
11 + 5 = 16
```

**My Code:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int a = input.nextInt();
  int tempA = a;
  boolean durum = true;

  dondur(a, tempA, durum);

}

public static void dondur(int a, int tempA, boolean durum) {

  if (a >= -5 && durum == true) {
    System.out.println(a);
    dondur(a - 5, tempA, durum);
  }
  if (a < 0) {
    a = a + 10;
  }

  if (a <= tempA) {
    durum = false;
    System.out.println(a);
    dondur(a + 5, tempA, durum);
  }

  if (a > tempA) {
    return;
  }

}
```

**Expected result:**
`16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16`
**My Result:**
`16 11 6 1 -4 1 6 11 16 6 11 16 1 6 11 16 6 11 16 11 16 16`

Comment: What is the code supposed to be doing?

Comment: I agree with the first comment. In cases like this, writing a clear description of what the code is supposed to be doing is part of writing a good question. Even if it seems obvious to you, do not assume the example input / output and example code makes it obvious to others.After all, if the code has bugs, we could be mislead trying to interpret the code and examples.

Comment: Debugging is a good skill to have. If you expect to become a professional or otherwise regularly create software, it will be a necessary skill. I suggest you run this code in a debugger. A debugger allows you to set a break point, and then run the rest of the code step-by-step, while monitoring variables.

Comment: By the way, `if (a > tempA) {  return; }` is odd. No code follows, so it will return regardless of whether the `if` statement evaluates to `true` or `false`.

Comment: If `a >= -5 && durum == true` you call the method recursively, but don't exit the method. That means that if you call it as `dondur(16, 16, true)`, that invocation calls both `dondur(11, 16, true)` and `dondur(21, 16, false)`. Add a return after each recursive call to `dondur` and you get the result you want.

Comment: it would be easier (simpler) to have two methods and discard the `durum` variable (and an `if`) - one to *count* down and the second for *upwards*

Comment: I added return after each recursive call and code fixed but why ı added return each recursive call What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You think too complicated. Keep in mind that applying recursion is taking advantage of a call stack.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    dondur(16);
}

static void dondur(int n) {
    System.out.println(n);
    if (n < 0) return;
    dondur(n - 5);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```